# Adding time to d3 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an area chart that thanks to some people on Stack Overflow I finally got working. Now I need to add some date to the beginning and the end dates that come from the data.

```
dataDefect.forEach(function(d) {
  d.projectDate = parseDate(d.projectDate);
  d.severity = +d.severity[0];
});

x.domain(d3.extent(dataDefect, function(d) { return d.projectDate; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataDefect, function(d) { return d.severity + 10; })]);
```

How do I add 30 days to the date so that I can draw some trends lines that show what might happen 30 days from now?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here -  [D3.js: calculate x-axis time scale for bar graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853873/d3-js-calculate-x-axis-time-scale-for-bar-graph)

```
var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
var nxExtent = [d3.time.day.offset(xExtent[0], -20), d3.time.day.offset(xExtent[1], 20)];
x.domain(nxExtent);
```

Thanks!