# D3.js time scale: nicely-spaced ticks at month intervals?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3.js to create some simple bar graphs, and was using the `d3.time.scale()` for the x-axis.
But, I stumbled upon one irregularity (or so it seems to me, although of course, I'm wrong :P)

When I generate the scale with ticks at monthly intervals, the difference between the ticks is **not** equal.

```
scaleX = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, 1000])
  .domain([new Date('2014-01'), new Date('2014-12')])

scaleX(new Date("2014-01"))  // 0
scaleX(new Date("2014-02"))  // 9.28...  (diff ~ 9.3)
scaleX(new Date("2014-03"))  // 17.66... (diff ~ 8.4)
scaleX(new Date("2014-04"))  // 26.94... (diff ~ 9.3)
```

This causes the bars in the graph to be unevenly spaced, leading to ugly graphs...

What's the correct way to evenly space out the bars with months as ticks? I realize that there is the possibility to use an `ordinal` scale to do this, but it doesn't feel right, also the ordinal scale would not draw ticks for months for which I don't have any data.

---

Edit: a little clarification on the question:
Since SO is for programmers, I only asked the "correct way" to make the ticks evenly spaced out. But what I really want to ask is this:

**Is is acceptable** to display time-charts with ticks of unequal length?

Comment: makes sense since months have varying number of days..

Comment: Yes, I agree that it makes perfect sense from a logical point of view. But it's not really 'aesthetically' sensible if you know what I mean...

Comment: Use an ordinal scale. You can always add "dummy" elements if you want empty months to show up.

Comment: perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186366/d3-js-evenly-spaced-bars-on-a-time-scale could help..

Comment: I'm very new to D3, so excuse my asking this... but won't it run counter to d3's declarative style of generating graphs?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How would using an ordinal scale not be declarative?

Comment: No, using the ordinal scale is not the problem... Finding the missing months, and adding them "by hand" or programmatically is...